# usb bootable stick crashed

Tags: boot, wireless, grub2

I was installing ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows from bootable usb pen drive. But the installation failed. Now the my computer is not starting even with windows. It shows grab error. What should i do.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the usb and select `try ubuntu`.Connect to the internet,open up the terminal by pressing ctrl+alt+t and then run following commands to install boot-repair,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

After that a dialog box appears,select `Recommende Repair` option.It will reinstall `grub` and your grub menu will appear on startup.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

As you said your USB crashed! you may want to make a fresh bootable again!

Use [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

All detailed instructions are given on the page..

After this Boot-repair you will get GRUB from which you will be able to boot into windows

If your ubuntu is installed properly then ubuntu will also boot properly otherwise you may have to ***reinstall ubuntu***!